# Initialize golang slice with int numbers from 0 to N

Tags: go, initialization, slice

I am almost certain that I read about a simple "tricky" way to initialize slice of ints with the numbers from 0 to N, but I cannot find it anymore.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Just a thought, `iota` might be what you remember, although this is for const and I know no way to use it on a slice.

Answer (score 13):

You just use make passing `N` for the length then use a simple for loop to set the values...

```
mySlice := make([]int, N)
for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
      mySlice[i] = i
}
```

Here's a full example on play; https://play.golang.org/p/yvyzuWxN1M

Comment: Did I read an one line way to do this for some other language? I am new to go.

Comment: @gsf probably yes. There are many languages where this can be done in one line but it's cannot be done in Go. You can use what's referred to as 'composite literal' syntax to allocate and initialize in the same statement but that requires you to write out the values so it would not work when you have an arbitrary length `N`. One line of code, three lines of code, what difference does it really make? It's easy to read and understand at a glace, that's what's really important.

Comment: yeap, it does not matter, unless you are working in a  competitive company and if you miss a detail like this everyone will start picking on you

Comment: I think range is better `for i := range mySlice { mySlice[i] = i }`

Comment: I would agree that it's a bit more concise however I would also say you would be much better served thinking about things other than how to most eloquently write a trivial for loop. Like I have a major pet peeve with developers who are so concerned with this kind of crap, worry about the bugs in your code or the applications performance or the user experience.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal you make software engineering sounding so tense. There is a place for all important aspects that you are talking about, but there is also a place for enjoying what you do, and if for someone it means expressing things in the most elegant way in the language they use - so be it. It is not going to be more "harmful" to your project than any other hobby you might have, like watching cute puppy images.

Comment: In my experience bugs are typically introduced by something as little as changing one of the `N` in your answer but forgetting to change the other.